# How do I keep folder tree and publish websites in TFS 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, tfsbuild

I have a visual studio solution that consists of several web applications, windows services and other class libraries. I am in the process of configuring it for continuous integration with TFS 2010.

The default build template puts every binary in the drop folder, and creates a _PublishedWebsites folder in which it publishes every web application. I do not want that because I need to separate the files that belong to one service from the files that belong to the another service.

I have followed the steps in [TFS 2010 BUILD SERVER: Can not keep folder tree in the drop location](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/tfsbuild/thread/a62a6f98-ec44-46c1-a0d0-7f441f0db973) to put each output in its own folder. That works well, but now my web applications are no longer published. The project is compiles and its binaries are placed in a sub-folder inside the drop folder, but it is missing all the other files, like Web.config, aspx, css, etc.

I could probably use two build templates, one for web applications, and the other one for windows services, but I'd rather have a single build template. How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you have a website MySite and a web service MyService and they are different solutions but you want them to build off of one build definition?

Comment: No, they are in the same solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use separate build process for each web application? Creating multiple build processes and multiple build definitions is very easy. You can copy or branch template process and then create a new build definition for each of them.

Comment: I'd like to keep it on the same build template. It would make it easier to manage.